# El comando "bash init.sh" no crea la carpeta ".homestead"

Tags: php, laravel-5

[image: Desde Hace algún tiempo bno consigo crear esa carpeta con el comando bash init.sh que esta dentro de la carpeta homestead.]

que podrá ser? 
Sólo funcionó una vez...despues eliminé esa carpeta junto con .ssh y al volver a intentar el proceso ..no funcionó más :(
He desinstalado el Oracle VirtualBox, tambien el vagrant y el Gib..luego he vuelto a instalarlos...

Comment: Que código tiene el `init.sh`? o puedes al menos indicar de donde lo sacaste?

Comment: Descargando el repositorio de homestead mediante:git clone https://github.com/laravel/homestead.git Homestead.

Comment: buscaste en la carpeta /Homestead/ ? el script no crea ningún directorio mira el [código fuente](https://github.com/laravel/homestead/blob/master/init.sh). Probablemente lo creaste en otra situación

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/homestead

Answer (score 1):

La nueva versión de homestead ya no crea la carpeta ~/.homestead/ ahora el archivo Homestead.yaml se encuentra dentro de la carpeta que descargas del git, una vez corras el comando bash.sh dicho archivo se creará.

Saludos!

Comment: Cuando continuo con el proceso me pide la carpeta homestead.yaml no encontrado en la carpeta .homestead!

Comment: Exacto en la doc viene, si pudiste ? Ahora bien tienes otras alternativas, valet o docker. Con valet puedes compartir tu app en la red local fácilmente, saludos!

Comment: @MIguel homestead.yaml no es una carpeta. Es el archivo de configuración, ya verificaste dentro de ~/Homested ? Ahí debe estar el archivo homestead.yaml después de correr el init.sh. Cuéntame como te fue

Comment: no funcionó me pide no la carpeta sino el archivo homestead.yaml; escribí mal; ubicado en la carpeta .homestead; y sí tambien esta en mi carpeta homestead principal tienes razón pero al instalar me pide ese archivo que se deberia encontrar en la carpeta .homestead.

Comment: @MIguel ya actualizaste tu carpeta ~/Homestead con git pull o si tienes cambios debes descartarlos y luego hacer hoy pull. También borra tu carpeta antigua ~/.homestead y luego corres vagrant reload --provision ok? Como te fue?